# Select and MultipleSelect do not fire events

Tags: java, gwt, gwtbootstrap3

I am working with GwtBootstrap3 0.9.3 and placed some Widgets on my from using the UiBinder. Checkboxes of the class org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.CheckBox and Buttons of org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.Button are working properly. They fire ClickEvents when I click on them.

But Selections of the classes org.gwtbootstrap3.extras.select.client.ui.MultipleSelect and org.gwtbootstrap3.extras.select.client.ui.Select don't fire any event when I click on them. Shouldn't they fire a com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent when making or changing a selection?

The eventhandlers are looking like this:

```
@UiHandler("simpleSelect")
void onValueChangeSimple(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
    do.somethingSimple();
}

@UiHandler("multiSelect")
void onValueChangeMultiple(ValueChangeEvent<List<String>> event) {
    do.somethingMultiple();
}
```

The ValueChangeEvent is never fired, when I click on these widges.

But when I set the values programmatically like

```
    simpleSelect.setValue("Item 1" , true);
```

the ValueChangeEvent will be fired and do.somethinSimple() will be called.

What goes wrong? What can I do to make these selection widgets firing ValueChangeEvents by using the UI?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following implementation with GwtBootstrap3Extras 0.9.3 + GWT 2.7 + SuperDevMode.

Inherit in the *.gwt.xml: `<inherits name="org.gwtbootstrap3.extras.select.Select"/>`

*.ui.xml with namespace `xmlns:select="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.extras.select.client.ui`:

```
<select:Select ui:field="simpleSelect">
    <select:Option>A</select:Option>
    <select:Option>B</select:Option>
    <select:Option>C</select:Option>
</select:Select>
<select:MultipleSelect ui:field="multiSelect">
    <select:Option>A</select:Option>
    <select:Option>B</select:Option>
    <select:Option>C</select:Option>
</select:MultipleSelect>
```

ViewImplementation:

```
@UiField
Select simpleSelect;

@UiField
MultipleSelect multiSelect;

@UiHandler("simpleSelect")
void onValueChangeSimple(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
    GWT.log("single changed");
}

@UiHandler("multiSelect")
void onValueChangeMultiple(ValueChangeEvent<List<String>> event) {
    GWT.log("multi changed");
}
```

This is working fine. Whenever I select an option from Select or MultipleSelect the message is logged to the browser console. If you configure your project the same way it should work. Otherwise you have another issue (then you should post your UiField-definition, *ui.xml,...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My code looks very similar to yours. The only difference I notice is, that the items of the selection are declared as attributes. <select:Option>A</select:Option> will be <select:Option text="A" value="A"/>. The selections are also inside FlowPanels. But that still doesn't work. It is compiled and run with JDK 8 and Spring Boot.

Comment: My *.ui.xml looks like this:    <ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"     xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"    xmlns:b="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui"    xmlns:b.gwt="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.gwt"    xmlns:select="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.extras.select.client.ui">

Comment: If I use attributes `<select:Option text="A" value="A"/>` it is also working. Shouldn't be the problem. Java 1.7 and 1.8 are tested by me.

Comment: Do you use GWT 2.7 or 2.8 Beta?

Comment: Its GWT 2.7 and GwtBootstrap 0.9.3.

Comment: Then it should work fine like this. I tested it with GWT 2.7. The dependecies are correct and you also inherited something like `<inherits name="org.gwtbootstrap3.GwtBootstrap3NoTheme" />`?  **Do you use the gwt-bootstrap3 or gwt FlowPanels?** Try it inside a simple `org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.html.Div`